# How to determine the last instruction in a function?

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly

Suppose you want to analyse a disassembled ARM function how does one determine where the function ends?

I was looking for a `BX LR` sequence but that is not 100% reliable.

Comment: Consider, `void foo(int a) { if(a>0) return 1; else return 0; }`.  There are quite likely two return sights.  As a matter of fact, the ARM *ABI* has been designed to make a return as fast as possible.  There are instructions like `ldm sp, {r4-r12,sp,pc}` or `pop {r4-r12,pc}`.  The single instruction can be placed at return points.  The contrary *function entry* is usually only one point unless it is a `static` function with aggressive optimization.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, `attribute((cleanup,myfunc))` can be used.  See [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

Comment: What exactly are you after? Like others said, a function can have multiple exit points, and there's a number of possible implementations for one. `mov pc, lr` is not unheard of. So `ldr pc,...`. If you're after partitioning the code area into functions, that's a whole different task.

Comment: Or just `b foo` as in the tail call case.  It would be most helpful to describe more about what you are trying to do.  You maybe trying to locate an address range of where the function is active **OR** trying to install a hook when the function exit.  Those are two different type of tasks.  Gcc provides features to do them.  If you are trying to do *basic block* analysis for a [decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/decompiling/info), then this is tough.

Answer (score 4):

from an assembly/machine code define "function".  there really isnt such a thing and as a result they dont really end.  Ultimately a compiled function will end in a restoration of the program counter to return to the instruction after the call to the function.  There is the obvious bx lr, and mov pc,lr and pop {...,pc}.  but it doesnt always have to use one of those three  (pop {r0}, mov pc,r0).  And then there are tail optimizations where if the last thing in the function is a call to another function the optimization is to branch rather than call, the return from that function ends up returning from the prior instruction call instead.

Looking at your other question that probably lead to this one, you would need to trace all possible execution paths from the call to the function to the return to the address that follows it, and all the instructions that might be touched could be considered part of that function.  Returns at the end of a function is just an illusion of high level languages, it doesnt have to be implemented that way.